# Supported methods: GET, HEAD but not POST

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-6

I want to save the data from a modal form to my database. The modal that I use is a modal from a Bootstrap. I place it in `main.blade.php` and I create an AuthControler with artisan without -r. and add a new route into web.php. If you ask why I didn't use `php artisan make:auth` well, it's because it's more complicated to edit the whole code in my HTML that I already made it from the first time IMO.

**main.blade.php**

```
{{-- modal register  --}}
<div id="modal-register" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-register">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    @csrf
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nama Lengkap</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="input-email" class="form-control" required="required"
                               placeholder="ex:abcdefg@gmail.com">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="input-password" class="form-control"
                                   required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>Konfirmasi Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password-confirmation" id="input-password" class="form-control"
                                   required="required" placeholder="Masukkan kembali password anda">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right service-btn" value="Register">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{-- modal register end  --}}
```

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getRegister()
    {
        return view('Register');
    }

    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        dd('ok');
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```php
// register
route::get('/register','AuthController@getRegister');
route::post('/register','AuthController@postRegister');

// login
route::get('/login','AuthController@getLogin');
route::post('/login','AuthController@postLogin');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all set action for your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('register') }}">
```

It is better to use post method only for registration but if you want both post and get change your route to:

```
route::match(['get', 'post'], '/register','AuthController@postRegister');
```

see also: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: use url in action

Answer (score 2):

Your form has no action set, so it will use the current URL.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Set the `action` to where you want the form POSTed to:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('register') }}">
```

Comment: and now i got "Route [register] not defined. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\web-desa\resources\views\layout\main.blade.php)" error

Answer (score 1):

**you miss the put route in your form**

*just put it*

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('register') }}">
```